# Сохранение передаваемых params во vueRouter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Есть динамический роут, который выводит отфильтрованный список товаров, фильтрация происходит в getter во vuex, все бы ничего, но если перезагрузить страницу находясь в этом компоненте список не отобразиться тк параметры для фильтрация из родительского компонента не передались. Пробовал использовать хуки, и  keep-alive, не помогло. Подскажите как решить данную проблему или посоветуйте бест практисы в таких случаях.
[image: [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "name" [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "type"]

[image: Здесь я передаю параметры из родительского компонента, которые будут использованы при фильтрации и вывода определенного списка товаров.]
[image: Геттер который фильтрует список]

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь добавлять код в виде текста, а не в виде картинке. Когда код в виде текста его легче читать, его можно скопировать и по нему можно провести поиск.

Comment: Покажи как ты регистрируешь этот динамический роут

Comment: @RavenTheX 

  {
  path: '/tobacco/:brand',
  name: 'v-catalog',
  props: true,
  component: vCatalog
  },

Comment: path: '/tobacco/:brand' а type откуда должен взяться?

Comment: Да и вообще что то вы не так поняли, динамически роуты не для этого нужны. Например у меня есть массив карточек и мне нужно сделать отдельную страницу каждой карточки card/:id. А у вас там 100500 каких то параметров

Comment: @RavenTheX

<router-link :to="{name: 'v-catalog', params: {brand: categoriesData.name, name: categoriesData.name, type: categoriesData.type}}">

почему 100500 параметров, 3 параметра, вот сюда берется type

Comment: Так вы зарегистрировали роут с одним параметром ':brand', а передаете три

Comment: @RavenTheX 2 параметра уходят в props компонента

Comment: Какие пропсы?) Пропсы не есть параметры url. Читайте документацию

Comment: @RavenTheX а как мне передать пропсы?

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html
Но я пологаю что вам понадобится vuex

Comment: @RavenTheX 
Когда props установлено в значение true, значения route.params будут устанавливаться входными параметрами компонента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [входные параметры](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0) во [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/), вы можете создать фильтр данных по этим параметрам.

Для этого:

1. Создаете роуты. Для передачи входных параметров, можете использовать функцию, объект, булевы значения. Обратите внимание, когда используете булево значение как `true` - `route.params`  будут устанавливаться входными параметрами компонента(это касается только `route.params`). В примере ниже используется функция, которая позволяет приводить параметры к другим типам, комбинировать статические значения с значениями из маршрута(позволяет использовать как `route.params` так и `route.query.*`):

   ```
   routes: [
      {
        path: "/",
        component: vcatalog,
      },
      {
        path: "/products/",
        component: vcatalog,
      },
      {
        path: "/products/:brand",
        component: vcatalog,
        props: (route) => ({ // функции генерации входных параметров
          type: route.query.type, 
          brand: route.params.brand,
        }),
      },
    ],
   ```
2. Создаете компонент, который используется в роутах, как:

   ```
   const vcatalog = Vue.component("vcatalog", {
    store,
    props: ["brand", "type"], // инициируем необходимые параметры
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["GET_PRODUCTS", "SORTED_PRODUCT"]),
    },
    template: `<div>
    <p>Входные параметры (props)</p>
    <pre>{{ $props }}</pre>
    <hr>
    <template v-if="brand && type"><ul>
        <li v-for="product in SORTED_PRODUCT(brand,type)"> {{ product.text }} ({{ product.type }}/ {{ product.brand }}) </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="product in GET_PRODUCTS"> {{ product.text }} ({{ product.type }}/ {{ product.brand }}) </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
    </pre>
    </div>`,
    });
   ```

И на выходе вы получите маршруты, которые будут содержать входные параметры, которые будут внедрены в ваш компонент и доступными для использования их в вашей дальнейшей логике (фильтрация и прочее)

Привожу рабочий пример

```js
const {
  mapGetters
} = Vuex;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: [{
        id: 1,
        text: "Продукт 1",
        type: "type1",
        brand: "brand1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Продукт 2",
        type: "type2",
        brand: "brand2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: "Продукт 3",
        type: "type1",
        brand: "brand2"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        text: "Продукт 4",
        type: "type1",
        brand: "brand1"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        text: "Продукт 5",
        type: "type2",
        brand: "brand2"
      },
    ],
  },
  getters: {
    GET_PRODUCTS: (state) => (brand) => {
      return brand ? state.products.filter((p) => p.brand === brand) : state.products;
    },
    SORTED_PRODUCT: (state) => (brand, type) => {
      return state.products.filter(
        (p) => p.brand === brand && p.type === type
      );
    },
  },
});

const vcatalog = Vue.component("vcatalog", {
  store,
  props: ["brand", "type"],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["GET_PRODUCTS", "SORTED_PRODUCT"]),
  },
  template: `<div>
    <p>Входные параметры (props)</p>
    <pre>{{ $props }}</pre>
    <hr>
    <template v-if="brand && type"><ul>
        <li v-for="product in SORTED_PRODUCT(brand,type)"> {{ product.text }} ({{ product.type }}/ {{ product.brand }}) </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="product in GET_PRODUCTS(brand)"> {{ product.text }} ({{ product.type }}/ {{ product.brand }}) </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </pre>
  </div>`,
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: "/",
      redirect: '/products'
    },
    {
      path: "/products/",
      component: vcatalog,
      name: 'catalog'
    },
    {
      path: "/products/:brand",
      name: 'brand',
      component: vcatalog,
      props: (route) => ({
        type: route.query.type,
        brand: route.params.brand,
      }),
    },
  ],
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  watch: {
    "$route.fullPath": {
      handler: function(path) {
        this.setNewPath(path);
      },
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.setNewPath();
  },
  methods: {
    goPath() {
      this.$router.push(this.path);
    },
    setNewPath(path) {
      this.path = path || this.$route.fullPath;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.router-link-active {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.8.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-view></router-view>
  <label for="input">Текущий URL</label>
  <hr>
  <input id="input" v-if="path" type="text" name="path" v-model="path" style="width: 100%; padding: 10px" @keyup.enter="goPath" />
  <p>Тестовые URL</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link exact :to="{name: 'catalog'}">/products</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link exact to="/products/brand2?type=type2">/products/brand2?type=type2</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link exact to="/products/brand1?type=type1">/products/brand1?type=type1</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link exact :to="{path: '/products/brand1' }">/products/brand1</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link exact :to="{name: 'brand', params: { brand: 'brand2'} }">/products/brand2</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link exact :to="{name: 'brand', params: { brand: 'brand2'}, query: { type: 'type1' } }">/products/brand2?type=type1</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```